# Node.js: initiate pg.Pool()

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, pg

As per [example](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) (*db.js*)

```
const pg = require('pg');

const client_config = {...};

const pool = new pg.Pool(client_config);

pool.on('error', function(err, client) {
  console.error('idle client error', err.mesae, err.stack);
});

module.exports.query = function(text, values, callback) {
  return pool.query(text, values, callback);
};

module.exports.connect = function(callback) {
  return pool.connect(callback);
};
```

and within an *express* (generated) application, do I have to initiate/require the Pool (*db.js*) in my *app.js*/on app start-up or do I simply require the *db.js* within my data models (respectively required in my routes)? Intuitively I would initiate the Pool on start-up rather than on each connection to the routes to avoid multiple initiations, but I am fairly new to *Node.js*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll a little further -- there are usage examples.

The reason this works is thanks to Node's module caching. The first time db.js is required, all the init code executes immediately. Subsequent `require` calls return the already-initialized module from the cache so the pool is already connected. In Express, you can avoid requiring db.js all over the place by using `app.set('db', db);` to attach the module to the Express application. You can then invoke `req.app.get('db').query(...)` in your route code.

If your data needs are complex enough to involve models, you may want to look into higher-level data access libraries since `pg` is more of a driver (think JDBC if you've done any Java). There are a lot of options ranging from minimal data mappers (I maintain [MassiveJS](https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js)) to query builders ([Knex](http://knexjs.org/)) to full-scale ORMs ([Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize)).

Comment: I found Express to be curse and blessing for a Node beginner, it's all 'yeah just generate and let's go' but, for me, it's ease obscures much of the core principles. I did read the examples but got confused about the one-time-init-warning. It's time to dive into the module system and export functionality! Thank you! BTW I looked into MassiveJS and Sequelize a while ago but decided to work with pg for a start and setup a scaleable structure with a minimum of low level DB data calls first...some people want to see beautiful things very soon, after that there will be time for a proper backend ,)